# can i delete guestadditions.iso after i installed it and rebooted in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox

by the way i cant seem to get it to run smooth, i keep having a 10 second delay,
Ive given it 128mb of video memory.  1280mb of base memory & it is using one processor because my pc is coreduo.

Comment: How did you install virtualbox? Which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can delete guestadditions.iso safely, because it contains only **installers**. After you installed your stuff, you don't need it anymore.

Comment: oh ok thanks.. this is my first time using virtualbox & ubuntu.. also if you all dont mind me asking.. whenever i shut it down via acpi shutdown button it seems to restart but never shuts down or turn back on..